# char array length changed after I change another value in the struct

Tags: c++, parsing, unions

so I encountered a weird situation here.

I'm trying to write a program that can parse boolean expression and logic expression such as: (salary * 2 > 10000) AND gender = 'M'.

I used a struct called Node to represent each operation at different levels based on the concept in here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram.

My Node construct is

```
class Node {

int type;
union
{
    int i;
    double f;
    char c[LINESIZE];

    char buf[LINESIZE];

    char tname[LINESIZE];
    char attr[LINESIZE];

    struct Node *p[2];  // points to operands of an expression;
    struct Node *q; //
} value;

bool eval_b();
Node* eval_e();
Node* eval_t();
Node* eval_f();
};
```

value.buf stores the actual expression.

```
enode = T(E_ptr); // Create a TERM Node and parse the next token

if(enode == NULL){
    cout << "Error: T() returns NULL" <<endl;
    return(NULL);
}

while(token_type == '+' || token_type == '-'  )
{
    E_ptr = exp_p; //Move the pointer in the input

    flag++;

    // Initialize a node
    op = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    strcat(op->value.buf, enode->value.buf);

    size_t len;
    if(token_type == '+'){

        op->type = ADD;
        strcat(op->value.buf, " + ");

        // The first len here!!!
        len = strlen(op->value.buf);
        cout << "after + , the len is:" << len << endl;
    }
    else if(token_type == '-'){
        op->type = MINUS;

        strcat(op->value.buf, " - ");
    }

    op->value.p[0] = enode;

    // The second len here!!!
    len = strlen(op->value.buf);
    cout << "before parsing + right , the len is:" << len << endl;

    op->value.p[1] = T(E_ptr);

    strcat(op->value.buf, op->value.p[1]->value.buf);

    if (op->value.p[1] == NULL){
        cout <<"Error: Some expression is expected after '+' or '-'." << endl;
        free(op);
        return(NULL);
    }
    operand = op;
}

if(flag == 0){
    op = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    op->type = EXPRESSION;
    op->value.q = enode;
    strcpy(op->value.buf, enode->value.buf);
    operand = op;
}

return operand;
```

my input is height + 0.3 > 2.0
The len can yield a good length which is 9. ("height + ")
But the len is reduced to 3 after I pass enode to op->value.p[0]. And when I print it out, it becomes "�A�".

What's going wrong here?

Comment: `strcat(op->value.buf, enode->value.buf);` `strcat` assumes that its parameters are pointers NUL-terminated strings. However, `op->value.buf` is a pointer to random uninitialized garbage.

Comment: You probably want to use a hierarchy of `Node` types with a virtual function called `eval`, rather than have one single `Node` type that has to do everything. It'll be much easier to reason about.

Comment: `op->value.p[0] = enode; len = strlen(op->value.buf);` You cannot read from one member of the union after you've assigned to another. Only one member is "active" at any given time - the one most recently assigned.

Comment: Try writing C++ instead of C.